# php datetime difference between datetime and datetime+int days

Tags: php, datetime

Trying to use the datetime in database and add a variable amount of days to it, then find the difference between the old date and new date and display it. I've reference http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php and

```
$postdate = $row["dated"]; // db value(datetime) assume 2016-04-12 18:35:00
$timelength = $row["timelength"]; // db value(int) assume 180
//Start decode and organizing
$time1 = new DateTime($postdate);
$time111 = date_add($time1, date_interval_create_from_date_string(''.$timelength.' days'));
$time211 = $time111->diff($time1);
$time222 = $time211->format('%d days %h hours %i minutes');
```

$time222 echo output is 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes

It should be 170 days ## hours ## minutes
I tried several approaches from the manual, Please don't ban me from SO.

Answer (score 4):

```
$time111 = date_add($time1, ...);
```

changes `$time1` to the new value as well as assigning it to `$time111`

Instead, do

```
$time1 = new DateTime($postdate);
$time2 = clone $time1;
$time111 = date_add($time2, date_interval_create_from_date_string(''.$timelength.' days'));
```

Comment: Well, it's not outputting 0d0h0m anymore, now if $timelength equals 7 it $time222 echos 7d0h0m, or 30d0h0m for 30 days, but 27d0h0m for 180 days. Ah the bliss.

Comment: How else could I approach this? Hmm. Maybe get rid of date_add and DateTime and go another route.

Comment: The documentation of DateInterval::format (http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) explains this. `%d` outputs the number of days not covered by months, while `%a` outputs the total number of days. Check the difference between `'%a days %h hours %i minutes'` and `'%m months %d days %h hours %i minutes'`.